# Openerp sheduler method: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, odoo

I created a module in Openerp, and it has the following file:
http://pastebin.com/91RLuTQh

and it works, i put the _start_syncro method into the sheduler, but whenever i tries to run it gives a strange error:

```
2013-02-04 10:01:40,658 6788 ERROR nagel_test openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Call of self.pool.get('res.partner')._start_syncro(cr, uid, *()) failed in Job 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_cron.py", line 132, in _callback
    method(cr, uid, *args)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/panda_partner/partner.py", line 57, in _start_syncro
    csvrow[4] = csvrow[4].decode("utf-8")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And whatever i do, it will always drop an error at line 57 exactly! 
I dont know why.

Comment: what are you getting in "csvrow" variable? problem may be with "csvrow" result data, not with scheduler method.

Comment: The problem is: whatever is on line 57: be ita list, ora vraiable, or just string. it will stop at line 57 with that error. No mather what. Also i copied that code into a normal pythonscript and ran it. And it worked withouth a glitch.

Comment: suggesting you, to check for csvrow result and csv file. as it seems "csvrow" list variable do not have all keys. as defined in link. means csv file do not have proper format or missing some details.

Comment: Sadly it has. i copied the code out and run it by itself withouth Openerp, and it worked. no error.

Comment: you may want to try the new http://help.openerp.com/ forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my Error: Seems like simply upgrading my module inside Openerp isn't enough. I need a full restart so my actual modification to work...